# Issues extending python in-built types with additional attributes and methods

Tags: python, oop

I'm currently creating a container for data that are of built-in python types. The data provided is of an unknown built-in type.
Since built-in types can't have their attributes and methods added/modified.

However, I have issues with instantiation of the inherited class.

NOTE: The following code would be inside of another class

With this code:

```
def createContainer(data):

    dataType = type(data)

    class container(dataType):
        def __init__(self, data):
            super().__init__(data)
            ## Instantiate the container attributes here


    return container(data)
```

Of the types I tested, data of these types were properly created:

- List
- Dictionary
- Set
- Bytearray

However, this left a lot of types that wouldn't work, this would result in the error:

`TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)`

Question 1 - why is this error occur when I am only passing one argument regardless of the data type.

When attempting this route:

```
class container(dataType):
    def __init__(self, data):

        super().__init__()
        ## Instantiate the container attributes here
```

Of the types tested, data of these types were properly stored:

- String
- Integer
- Float
- Tuple
- Complex
- Byte
- Frozenset

The other types (list, dictionary, set, bytearray) were created, but were empty, and did not contain the data I passed.

Question 2a - I am not passing any argument to the super constructor, so why are the above types being initialized properly, when no data is being passed?

Question 2b - when i replace `super().__init__()` with `dataType.__init__(data)` I get the same results. I'm assuming they do the same thing in this instance, but how is that possible if we didn't provide the argument into `super().__init__()`

Question 3 - From what I can see, method 1 only works with mutable types. Whereas method 2, only works with immutable types. But how would this effect the way these types are instantiated?

Final Question - I know I could write conditionals in the constructor using `isinstance()` to check the type and create the container and initialize in the method that works. But is there a 'one size fits all' approach?

Comment: You aren't creating containers, btw. Honestly, it makes much more sense to simply use a wrapper, i.e. composition, instead of inheritance. In any case, what's happening is that for the immutable built-in types, you need to override `__super__`, they don't do anything with `__init__`

Answer (score 0):

The constructors in both classes are redundant. It sounds like you are aiming to create a data structure that works both for mutable and immutable data types. I doubt it will ever work.

Answer (score -1):

Most of your problems are due to the fact that `type(...)` doesn't return the parent class, but a `<class 'type'>`. So when you do `class container (dataType)`, you create a class of the type ... `type`.

```
# example
>>> type(str) #when you expect str, it returns ...
<class 'type'>
```

To solve this, change `dataType = type(data)` to `dataType = data.__class__`.

```
# second example
>>> "my data is str".__class__
<class 'str'>
```

EDIT:
When you do `super().__init__()` and get the error `TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)`, it's due to the fact that when you create a class with a `__init__` function, it's always `__init__(self, ...)`. In your case, `super()` returns the `object` class, and the `object`'s `__init__` function is defined as `__init__(self)` with no more arguments. So it expects one argument, `self`. But you don't pass it, and it raises an error. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: why do you think they are passing class objects to `type`? In any case, using `data.__class__` **will not solve this**, it is essentially equivalent to `type(data)`.